# How do I test asynchronous function throwing error with Tape?

Tags: node.js, testing, node.js-tape

I'm trying to test an async function that calls an API using Tape but I don't seem to be having much luck.  I've used Mocha/Chai and Jasmine before but I'm not sure how to do what I want here.

This is the function I want to test

```
const logicGetMovies = async (genre, page) => {

  numCheck(genre, 'genre')
  numCheck(page, 'page')
  stringCheck(process.env.API_KEY,'process.env.API_KEY')

  const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?with_genres=${genre}&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}&page=${page}&sort_by=vote_average.desc`

  try {
    return await axios.get(url)
  } catch (e) {
    throw new APIError(e.message)
  }
}
```

which relies on two helper functions that throw APIErrors (my own Error type)

```
const numCheck = (num, name) => {
  if (!num) throw new APIError(`${name} is missing`)
  if (typeof num !== 'number' || num <= 0) throw new APIError(`${name} must be a number greater than 0`)
}

const stringCheck = (string, name) => {
  if (!string) throw new APIError(`${name} is missing`)
  if (typeof string !== 'string') throw new APIError(`${name} must be of type string`)
}
```

I've tried this Tape test but it both fails and the error isn't caught

```
const test = require('tape')
const logic = require('../../logic')
const APIError = require('../../logic/APIError')

test('getMovies should throw error with missing genre',(t) =>{
  t.throws(logic.logicGetMovies(null,1),APIError,'genre is missing')

})
```

I tried changing it to `async` but that didn't help.

```
const test = require('tape')
const logic = require('../../logic')
const APIError = require('../../logic/APIError')

test('getMovies should throw error with missing genre', async (t) => {
  t.throws(logic.logicGetMovies(null, 1), APIError, 'genre is missing')
  t.end()
})
```

Clearly I'm lost here.  Any clues or answers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try changing: `t.throws(logic.logicGetMovies(null,1),APIError,'genre is missing')` to: `t.throws(() => logic.logicGetMovies(null,1),APIError,'genre is missing')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) never throws an error...

...it returns a `Promise` that may reject with an error.

So test the returned `Promise` to verify that it rejects with the expected error.

You'll need to [add `Promise` support to `tape`](https://github.com/substack/tape#other) with something like [`tape-promise`](https://github.com/jprichardson/tape-promise#readme).

Here is a simplified example:

```
const tape = require('tape');
const _test = require('tape-promise').default;
const test = _test(tape);

const func = async () => {
  throw new Error('the error');
};

test('should reject', async (t) => {
  await t.rejects(func(), Error, 'the error');  // Success!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I test async error throwing:

```js
test('fetchData()', async (t) => {
  try {
    await fetchData();
    t.fail('it should throws an error');
  } catch (e) {
    t.pass('it should throws an error');
  }
}
```

If the error throws, the catch block will catch the error and produces a passed test.

Otherwise, `t.fail()` will be executed and produces a failed test.